# How can I extract from title from name in a column?

Tags: r, regex, gsub, grepl

I have a column of names of the form "Hobs, Mr. jack" i.e. lastname, title. firstname. title has 4 types -"Mr.", "Mrs.","Miss.","Master." How can I search for each item in the column & return the title ,which I can store in another column ?

```
Name <- c("Hobs, Mr. jack","Hobs, Master. John","Hobs, Mrs. Nicole",........)
```

desired output - a column "title" with values - `("Mr","Master", "Mrs",.....)`

I have tried something like this:

```
f <- function(d) {
      if (grep("Mr", d$title)) {
                  gsub("$Mr$", "Mr", d$title, ignore.case = T)
           }
 }
```

no success >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(stringr)
> Name <- c("Hobs, Mr. jack","Hobs, Master. John","Hobs, Mrs. Nicole")
> str_extract(string = Name,pattern = "(Mr|Master|Mrs)\\.")
[1] "Mr."     "Master." "Mrs."
```

A fancier regex might exclude the period up front, or you could remove them in a second step.

Comment: This works..Thank you..i can take care of the period..I was also trying to separate the name column 
 separate(name, c("lastname", "title"), sep = "\\.")
& then separate the title column again , however it gives an error for the second separation

Answer (score 0):

Considering dataset name as df and column as Name. New column name would be title.

```
df$Title <- gsub('(.*, )|(\\..*)', '', df$Name)
```